# Asynchronous function callback return value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know I can pass the callback function to access the value，looks like [How to return value from an asynchronous callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function) but in my case , It need  execute the synchronous method so i can do action outside the callback,any tip to help?

```
var foo;

function getFoo(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        async: false
    })
            .done(function(respond) {
        var data = respond.data;
        doStuff(data, function(respond) { //This is callback from Asynchronous function
            callback(respond);
        })
    });
}

getFoo(function(respond) {
    foo = respond;
});

return foo; //How can I access foo value from respond
```

Comment: if `doStuff` is async then it won't work

Comment: also since `$.ajax()` in `getFoo()` is `async: false` you need to use the `success: function(){...}` callback format instead of `.done()` callback... see `As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done() or the deprecated jqXHR.success()`

Answer (score 0):

You can only return a value if the entire function is synchronous; in your case, `doStuff` is asynchronous, so you can't return `foo` like that (but it would be better to write the whole thing asynchronously anyway, since if you use jQuery's `async: false` option, it blocks the user interface until the AJAX result comes back).

Here's an example of how you could restructure your code:

```
function example(exampleCallback) { 
    function getFoo(callback){
        $.ajax({
            url: url
        })
        .done(function(respond) {
            var data = respond.data;
            doStuff(data,function(respond){ //This is callback from Asynchronous function
              callback(respond);
            })
        });
    }

    getFoo(function(respond){
        exampleCallback(respond);
    });
}

example(function(foo) {
    //do something with foo
});
```